# Can you reference individual tiles on a tilemap as transforms/gameobjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and coding in general and I'm trying to make a barebones autobattler just for fun. I'm trying to make a grid system for movement like auto chess and TFT have, but I'm having a bit of trouble. I want to be able to reference individual tiles on the map so that I can tell a unity to move to the left or right, up or down a tile etc.. I tried using the Tilemap feature for this but I can't find a way to individually reference the tiles as gameobjects or transforms to move to. Is this possible, and if not do you guys know of any other way to achieve a good grid movement system?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make the grid yourself and use Unity's tilemap only for the visual decorations. You know that all tiles have the same size. Then you can just compute the coordinates of every tile. For example if you want the tile in the third column of the fourth row relative to the origin, then its center is at

```
Vector2(3.5*tile_width, 4.5*tile_height)
```

All objects that can be on the tiles, should have row and column int variables that are updated accordingly. You can find out on what tile the user's mouse currently is by comparing against the virtual grid as well.

Comment: So would you recommend just individually placing the tiles? I'm sure there's a more elegant way of aligning them through the script.